# NHibernate Many-to-one cascade

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have the below two classes:

```
public class Project
{

    public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public virtual LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class LegalEntity
{
    public virtual int LegalEntId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with mappings as:

```
<class name="Project" table="Project" dynamic-update="true">
  <id name="ProjectId">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>  

  <property name="ProjectName" />
  <many-to-one name="LegalEntity" column="LegalEntId" fetch="join" cascade="all-delete-orphan" />


</class>
```

and

```
<class name="LegalEntity" table="LegalEnt" dynamic-update="true">

  <id name="LegalEntId">

    <generator class="native"/>

  </id>



  <property name="Name" />    

</class>
```

In database, Project table has a FK to LegalEntity's PK column. One Project will have only one legal entity. Different projects can have same legal entity. So thats the reason I have gone for many-to-one. Not sure if this is correct though.

Insert and update is working fine. But if I update a legal entity id in a project and that legal entity becomes orphan, I want it to be deleted. But its not happening. Am I wrong in understanding delete-all-orphan? If yes, how can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `many-to-one` cascade does not support `all-delete-orphan`, see:

- [5.1.10. many-to-one](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

> ```
> <many-to-one
>     ...
>     cascade="all|none|save-update|delete"              (4)
>     ...
> ```

Also, it would be almost impossible to handle this feature by NHibernate's session. Because it does not have to be clear, that the referenced `many-to-one` is really orphan. There should be some farther checks in DB... there could be other places referencing this table row...

Suggestion: do it in your code as a part of the DAO or Business Facade implementation. Check if there are really **no** dependencies, and then issue explicit `Delete()`

EXTEND: Here is a `QueryOver` syntax to get a list of all *"orphan"* LegalEntity

```
// subquery
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Project>()
    .Select(x => x.LegalEntity.LegalEntId);

// just these legal entities, which are NOT used
var query = session.QueryOver<LegalEntity>()
    .WithSubquery
      .WhereProperty(y => y.LegalEntId)
      .NotIn(subquery)
    ;

// orphans
var list = query
    .List<LegalEntity>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In SQL, I would have done the query:
 
select * from LegalEnt
where LegalEntId not in (select LegalEntId from Project)
 
Whats will be the equivalent query for this in NH?

Comment: Almost the same in NHibernate ;) Check http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-simpleexpressions where you can quickly get idea how to use `QueryOver` ... or ask here ;)

Comment: Thanks Radim. Your posts are very helful. I can't get it right to use QueryOver. If you can help me with converting the above SQL to NH I would really appreciate.

Comment: I will show you how... (maybe later today, but I will).

Comment: I extended my answer, think it should be what you could use to get a list of orphans... iterate it and delete them... also, maybe check this: DML - http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct

Answer (score 0):

Now `all-delete-orphan` and `delete-orphan` **have been implemented** for `many-to-one` as you can see in this [commit from Nov 19, 2014](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/3e4cf2a51b281b6c66e4363bd5ab4c3309257561).

<sup><sub>Those were not supported when the OP asked the questions or when [Radim Köhler wrote his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24237320/146513), but I think future visitors will appretiate the update.</sub></sup>

The [documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) is also updated and now says:

> cascade="all|none|save-update|delete|delete-orphan|all-delete-orphan"

<sup><sub>But the documentation is confusing now, because it still has the following note:

*The cascade attribute permits the following values: all, save-update, delete, none.*

So I've created [a defect](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3840) to fix that last part of the documentation.</sub></sup>