# NHibernate mapping One-to-One with Foreign Key Association

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have two table :

```
TableA :
    Id (identity)
    IdTableB(Foreign Key) Nullable
    ...

TableB :
    Id (identity)
    ...
```

I did that mapping :

ClassA (tableA)

```
...
m.ManyToOne<ClassB>(x => x.ClassB, map =>
{
     map.Column("IdTableB");
     map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
     map.Unique(true);
});
...
```

ClassB (tableB)

```
...
m.OneToOne<ClassA>(x => x.ClassA, map =>
{
     map.PropertyReference(x => x.ClassB);
     map.Constrained(false);
});   
...
```

Ok, the mapping is fine and select/save works fine.

Now I want to delete ClassB from a ClassA object, like that :

```
ClassA classA = session.Load(1);
classA.ClassB = null;
session.commit();
```

That update de tableA with null on IdTableB, but it do not delete the ClassB from tableB.

First, is it my mapping fine? Is there a better solution?

Second, how can I delete that ClassB object when I explicity delete from relation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tried to explain here: [NHibernate Many-to-one cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24234637/1679310),

> `Many-to-one` does not support cascade **`all-delete-orphan`**. And this kind of setting is able to delete entity, which is not referenced any more...

Other words, making `many-to-one` reference null - will not trigger delete.

So, mapping is ok, but functionality required above is not in place. Solution would be to explicitly delete the reference **`session.Delete(classA.ClassB)`**...